# Stabilizer proofs

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Please critique my proofs:

> Let $\ast$ define an action of $G$ on $X.$
>
> $(a)$ Show that for $g \in G$ and $x \in X$ one has $\operatorname{stab}_G(g \ast x) = g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}.$

$(i) \operatorname{stab}_G(g \ast x) \subseteq g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}:$
Let $a \in \operatorname{stab}_G(g \ast x).$ Then $a \ast (g \ast x) = \hspace{0.5mm} (i) \hspace{0.5mm} (ag) \ast x = g \ast x.$ Left multiplying the preceding equality $(i)$ by $g^{-1},$ we obtain $(g^{-1}ag) \ast x = (g^{-1}g) \ast x = 1_G \ast x = x.$ Thus $g^{-1}ag = b \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x).$ Combined with the fact that $a = gbg^{-1},$ we obtain $a \in g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}.$

$(ii) \operatorname{stab}_G(g \ast x) \supseteq g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}$: Let $a \in g\operatorname{stab}_G(x)g^{-1}.$ Then $a = ghg^{-1}$ where $h \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x).$ This implies that $ag = gh,$ and if we apply $\ast x$ to both sides, we obtain $(ag) \ast x = (gh) \ast x.$ This equals $a \ast (g \ast x) = g \ast (h \ast x) = g \ast x.$ Hence $a \in \operatorname{stab}_G(g \ast x). $
Combining $(i)$ and $(ii),$ we are done. $\text{ } \Box$

> $(b)$ Show that $\operatorname{stab}_G(x) \leqslant G.$

It is clear that $\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$ is non-empty, since $1_G \ast x = x$ for every $x \in X,$ and so $1_G \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x).$

$\operatorname{stab}_G(x)$ is also closed under products, since for $a,b \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x),$ it follows that $a \ast x = a \ast (b \ast x) = (ab) \ast x = x.$ Hence $ab \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x).$

Let $a \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x).$ Then $a \ast x = x.$ If we apply $a^{-1} \ast$ to both sides of the preceding equality, we obtain $a^{-1} \ast x = a^{-1} \ast (a \ast x),$ and since $a^{-1} \ast (a \ast x) = (aa^{-1}) \ast x = 1_G \ast x = x,$ it follows that $a^{-1} \ast x= x,$  demonstrating that $a^{-1} \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x). \text{ } \Box$

> $(c)$ Show that for every $x \in X$ one has $x \in X^G \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{stab}_G(x) = \{g \in G : g \ast x = x \}= G.$

An element $x \in X$ is called a $G$-fixed point if $g \ast x = x$ for every $g \in G.$ The set of $G$-fixed points of $X$ is denoted $X^G = \{x \in X:g \ast x = x \text{ for every } g \in G \}.$

Suppose that $x \in X^G =\{x \in X: g \ast x = x \text{ for all } g \in G \}.$ This means that $g \ast x = x$ for every $g$, so it follows that $g \in \operatorname{stab}_G(x)$ for all $g \in G.$ Thus $\operatorname{stab}_G(x) = G.$

Similarly, if $G = \operatorname{stab}_G(x)$, then $g \ast x = x$ for every $g \in G,$  and so $x \in X^G. \text{ } \Box$

Comment: You did well until part (c). You need to show that if $x \in X^G$ the stabilizer of $x$ is all of $G$, and vice versa. Assuming $X^G = X$ means the action is trivial, which cannot be assumed to be the case. The problem begins with the sentence: "Suppose that for every..." which should start like so: "Suppose that $x \in X^G$..."